# Slow navigation to view model with cyclic references

Tags: catel

I have WPF application and model with cyclic references like:

```
class A : ModelBase
{
    public FastObservableCollection<B> Collection {get; set;}
}

class B : ModelBase
{
    public A Parent {get; set;}
}
```

when I load 100+ instances and navigating to another ViewModel debug output is clogged with messages like:

```
...
20:40:36:751 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Creating new scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:752 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Custom function to create the scope is provided, creating custom scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:754 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 1
20:40:36:755 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:757 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 2
20:40:36:758 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Dereferencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 1
20:40:36:759 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Creating new scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:761 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Custom function to create the scope is provided, creating custom scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:762 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 1
20:40:36:763 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:765 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 2
20:40:36:766 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializer] [1] Serializing property VSMC.Models.ApplicationModel.CurrentChannel as xml element 'CurrentChannel'
20:40:36:768 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:769 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 2
20:40:36:771 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Dereferencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 1
20:40:36:772 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:774 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 3
20:40:36:775 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:776 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 4
20:40:36:778 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:779 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 5
20:40:36:780 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Dereferencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 4
20:40:36:781 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:782 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationContextScope`1[[Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializationContextInfo, Catel.Core, Version=5.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 2
20:40:36:783 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializerBase`1] [1] Using '0' serializer modifiers to deserialize type 'VSMC.Models.ChannelModel'
20:40:36:784 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Returning existing scope for type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with name 'Thread_1'
20:40:36:785 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Scoping.ScopeManager`1] [1] Referencing type 'Catel.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationScope' with scope name 'Thread_1', new ref count is 5
20:40:36:786 => [DEBUG] [Catel.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.XmlSerializer] [1] Serializing property VSMC.Models.ChannelModel.Id as xml element 'Id'
...
```

and application freezes for 10+ seconds. 
What I am doing wrong? Can I disable model serialization when navigating?

Comment: Please provide the VM, since that code is missing. But my guess is that you are using the Model attribute. If so, use the SupportIEditableObject = false inside the attribute.

Comment: I have changed base type of models to **DispatcherObservableObject** because no need validation. This is speed up navigation process dramaticaly.